# Awk command to format text output with custom record separator and field Separator

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file which has the data in the following manner :

```
1
2
3
end
4
5
6
```

I want an output in the form :

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

here the string "end" represents the record separator.
I am new to UNIX and used Awk to achieve this, I am sure there can be much easier and a better way.
Here is my attempt:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="end\n"; FS="\n"} { print $1 "\t"  $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4'} atestfile.awk
```

Comment: note that your `print `statement would look better if you said `-v OFS="\t" '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}`. This way, you separate the logic on _what_ you print from _how_ you do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I'd write it like this:

```
awk -v RS='end' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

The differences are that I've used `-v` to specify the record separator `RS` and the output field separator `OFS`. I've also used `$1=$1` to make awk "touch" each record (so that the format is changed to use `OFS`) and `1` at the end as a shorthand for `{print}` (since `1` is always True and the default action of `awk` on True is to print the record).

Comment: Touching records for FS conversion is a neat trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use `perl` (and yes, I know that's not quite what you asked, but given it's standard on Unix, I'll offer it anyway).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#read STDIN or a filename designated on command line. 
while (<>) { 
    #replace linefeeds with spaces. 
    s/\n/ /g;
    #Check for presence of "end"
    if (m/end/) {
        #insert linefeed
        print "\n";
    }
    else {
        print;
    }
}
```